# Geometric distribution, tossing a die

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [geometric distribution throwing a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279525/geometric-distribution-throwing-a-die)

Yesterday I posted a question which was answered but I disagree with the answer so I'd like to ask again so we can discuss it together :)

The problem says as follows: We throw a die repeatedly. X  and Y  denote, respectively, the number of rolls until we reach a 5  and 6 .
The aim is to compute $E[X|Y=5]$.

First question: If Y=5 (this means no 6 have come up in the first 4 rolls) then the probability of getting 5 in those rolls should be 1/5 instead of 1/6?

I have done some simulations to guess the expected number of rolls and I get always something around 5.8 which seems reasonable but I can't arrive to that answer algebraically or analitically.

Thanks a lot for you help! :)

Comment: If $Y$ is the number of rolls until we get a $6$, then $Y=6$ means that there is no $6$ in the first $5$ rolls, and it says nothing about whether there were any $5$’s.

Comment: Sorry there are mistypes... where it says "Y=6" it should say "Y=5"

Comment: and in fact what Im trying to compute, by the way, is $E[X|Y=5]$

Comment: Also, it's not clear, but it seems like when you say "then the probability of getting 5 in those rolls should be 1/5 instead of 1/6?" you mean the individual probability at each roll that you got a $5$, right? Because the probability that you got a $5$ somewhere in those first five rolls is never $1/6$ or $1/5."

Comment: But it still means that there is no $6$ in the first $4$ rolls, not that there is no $5$.

Comment: I've made the changes so now it should make sense, I'm so sorry. I mean that "knowing beforehand that no 6 has come up in the first rolls" should make 5 more probable to come up then..

Comment: It's generally a really bad idea to repost a question. There are a lot of really smart people here, and you essentially have hidden all the work that other people have done to both attempt to understand your problem (since we are right now trying to figure out what you actually mean) and to help you answer it.

Comment: It would be helpful to link the questions (and hence the two different accounts you must have created).  Thomas is quite correct in that by hiding the link between the two questions, you are creating a substantial amount more work for everyone (including yourself).  Disagreeing with or not understanding given answers is fine, but questions should be asked at your original question.  As a parenthetical side note, Einstein had a word for those who performed the same task over again and expected different results.  Surely, you must realize that the answers given here are not random, right?

Comment: I answered the problem yesterday, buy I believe I'm in error. Brian comes closest to what it should be, but he has a slight mistake. @Daniel The bijection doesn't work, but it doesn't really take into account the chance of not getting a 6 in the first 5 turns. I might edit the way to understand it.

Comment: Compare [Yesterday I posted a question which was answered but I disagree with the answer] to [Oh yes now I see it! Thanks sooo much! :D]. Sorry but I do not manage to reconcile these.

Comment: @did He ran a computer simulation and obtained an answer that was very different from what I gave. The bijection that I created was not correct. I've since edited the answer to take that into account. (I didn't realize that deleting the answer would also remove the previous edits, so that's not visible now.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the only information we have about a roll of a die is that we did not get a $6$, then the probability we got a $5$ is $\frac{1}{5}$. For given only that we did not get a $6$, the numbers $1$ through $5$ are equally likely.

One sloppy but intuitive argument goes as follows. Suppose we toss the die $6000$ times. Then we will get roughly $1000$ of each number. (More precisely, the *proportion* of each is very likely to be close to $\frac{1}{6}$.)

Now concentrate attention on the about $5000$ times we did not get a $6$. About $1000$ of these times, we got a $5$, so the probability we got a $5$ **given** we did not get a $6$ is $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: I see. How would the conditional expectation be computed then?

Comment: Yesterday I saw the answer to your previous question. The explanation there was good.

Comment: You think? but the result is far from what I get from my simulations..

Comment: Simulations for waiting time can be a little tricky, tails can be long, and mean is strongly affected by them. But nowadays computation is cheap, and a few million iterations should give very reliable results for the conditional expectation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I wrote the solution yesterday and it was wrong. Have since edited it, because I didn't properly take the $Y=5$ into actual consideration.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Apart from minor detail, your procedure was right.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed in a straightforward manner:

$$\tag{1}\Bbb E(X|Y=5)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 i\cdot P[X=i|Y=5]+E(X|Y=5, X> 5)P[X>5|Y=5].$$

We have 
$$\eqalign{
\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 i\cdot P[X=i|Y=5]
&=(1/5)\cdot 1+ (4/5)(1/5)\cdot 2+(4/5)^2(1/5)\cdot 3+(4/5)^3(1/5)\cdot 4+0\cr  
&=\textstyle{821\over625}.}
$$
and, noting that if both $Y=5$ and $X>5$, it's as if we "started over"
$$
E(X|Y=5, X> 5)= (\Bbb E(X)+5)=6+5= 11.
$$

Computing the required sum $(1)$, using $P[X>5|Y=5]=(4/5)^4$, we obtain
$$\Bbb E(X|Y=5)
=\textstyle{821\over625}+(4/5)^4\cdot11
\approx 5.8192.$$

Comment: I did it in the same manner as you (with the same result).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $Y=5$, then you know that you did not roll a $6$ on any of the first four rolls. Thus, $X=1$ with probability $\frac15$, $X=2$ with probability $\frac45\cdot\frac15$, $X=3$ with probability $\left(\frac45\right)^2\cdot\frac15$, and $X=4$ with probability $\left(\frac45\right)^3\frac15$. Clearly the probability that $X=5$ is $0$. For $n>5$ the probability that $X=n$ is $\left(\frac45\right)^4\left(\frac56\right)^{n-6}\cdot\frac16$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\Bbb E[X\mid Y=5]&=\sum_{k=1}^4k\left(\frac45\right)^{k-1}\frac15+\left(\frac45\right)^4\sum_{k\ge 6}k\left(\frac56\right)^{k-6}\frac16\\\\
&=\frac15\sum_{k=1}^4k\left(\frac45\right)^{k-1}+\frac16\left(\frac45\right)^4\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+6)\left(\frac56\right)^k\\\\
&=\frac15\sum_{k=1}^4k\left(\frac45\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac45\right)^4\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac56\right)^k+\frac16\left(\frac45\right)^4\sum_{k\ge 1}k\left(\frac56\right)^k\\\\
&=1.3136+\frac{0.4096}{1-5/6}+\frac16\left(\frac45\right)^4\left(\frac56\right)\sum_{k\ge 1}k\left(\frac56\right)^{k-1}\\\\
&=3.7712+\frac{256}{36\cdot125}\frac1{\left(1-\frac56\right)^2}\\\\
&=3.7712+\frac{256}{125}\\\\
&=5.8192\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Looks very much like what I computed but must have done some mistake computing the geometric sums.. but now we got two different answers :P

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, there’s a mistake; I just caught it and am in the process of fixing it.

Comment: The second sum should be $ (\frac {5}{6}) ^{k-6} \times (\frac {4}{5} )^5 \times \frac {1}{6} $

Comment: Ah! but then is exactly what I had.. strange because I think the whole sum does not give 1 (which should since it's a prob distribution)

Comment: @Calvin: I realized that almost as soon as I’d posted, but I think that your exponent of $5$ should be $4$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes the 5 should be a 4. I calculated 5.8192 like David